# How to apply masks to rectangle which fill with image object in kineticjs

Tags: kineticjs

I have researched many forums and tutorial to find the idea or solution to apply a different shape of masks to the rectangle which fill with image obj in Kinecticjs. But I have tried with different method but failed to achieve the final output.

For example :
Please get the image from here
http://postimg.org/image/5czqujzxb/

Anyone have idea with this? 
Thanks for advance for sharing the knowledge and solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KineticJS has built in support for rectangular clipping, but not for clipping to a path (like your heart).

Instead, you can create a custom Kinetic.Shape and use compositing to fill your heart-mask with your pattern.

Since KineticJS does not have built-in compositing, the trick is to get a reference to the actual html5 canvas context which KineticJS uses for drawing:

```
var maskedShape = new Kinetic.Shape({
  x: 20,
  y: 20,
  drawFunc: function(context) {

    // ctx is the actual html5 context used by this shape
    var ctx=context.canvas._canvas.getContext('2d');

  }
});
```

Then you can use html5 context's 'source-in' compositing to restrict your pattern to drawing only into the heart-mask:

```
ctx.drawImage(heartMaskImage,0,0);
ctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-in';
ctx.drawImage(patternImage,0,0);
```

Here is a Demo:

```js
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: 450,
  height: 450
});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

// put the paths to your images in imageURLs[]
var imageURLs=[];  
// push all your image urls!
imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/mask1.png");
imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/pattern1.jpg");

// the loaded images will be placed in images[]
var imgs=[];

var imagesOK=0;
loadAllImages(start);

function loadAllImages(callback){
  for (var i=0; i<imageURLs.length; i++) {
    var img = new Image();
    imgs.push(img);
    img.onload = function(){ 
      imagesOK++; 
      if (imagesOK>=imageURLs.length ) {
        callback();
      }
    };
    img.onerror=function(){alert("image load failed");} 
    img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
    img.src = imageURLs[i];
  }      
}

function start(){

  // the imgs[] array now holds fully loaded images
  // the imgs[] are in the same order as imageURLs[]

  var maskedShape = new Kinetic.Shape({
    x: 20,
    y: 20,
    drawFunc: function(context) {
      var ctx=context.canvas._canvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.save();
      ctx.drawImage(imgs[0],0,0);
      ctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-in';
      ctx.drawImage(imgs[1],0,0);
      ctx.restore();
    }
  });
  layer.add(maskedShape);
  layer.draw();

}
```

```css
body{padding:20px;}
#container{
 border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:450px;
  height:450px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v5.1.0.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```